# ionic 6 google account firebase

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-account

I am using ionic 6. when using the function loginwithgoogle using firebase , it's work perfectly without any error in te web. it's  take me to the right page "principal", but the task is setting the app in an Android mobile.  after putting the google account informations and click for login, it's take me to other page localhost/login not found.

```
async loginWithGoogle() {
  try {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(async (result: any) => {
      //console.log(result)
      const credential =
        GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      //console.log(credential)
      const googleCredentials = {
        id_token: result.user.accessToken,
        email: result.user.email,
        name: result.user.displayName
      };
      //console.log(googleCredentials)
      const body = JSON.stringify({
        google_credentials: googleCredentials
      });
      const parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
      const idToken = parsedBody.google_credentials.id_token;
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': idToken
      });
      const response: any = await this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/login`,
        body, {
          headers
        }).toPromise();
      this.token.setToken(response.token);
      await this.storage.set('auth-token', response.token);
      this.router.navigate(['/principal']);
    })
    //await this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new  firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error logging in with Google:', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code as text and not image

Comment: it's updating , thanks

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console? Please check the `Logcat` on Android for any error messages

Comment: no errores it's work perfetcky , it's just after putting the information and redirect to the firebase domain for the auth , it's open other page in the mobile and saying localhost/login not found , there is no error in the console

Answer (score 2):

On Android, you have to use the Firebase Android SDK.
There are already Capacitor plugins for this.

**Example**:

```
import { FirebaseAuthentication } from '@capacitor-firebase/authentication';
import {
  getAuth,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithCredential,
} from 'firebase/auth';

const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  // 1. Create credentials on the native layer
  const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithGoogle();
  // 2. Sign in on the web layer using the id token
  const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(result.credential?.idToken);
  const auth = getAuth();
  await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
};
```

[Source](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/blob/main/packages/authentication/docs/firebase-js-sdk.md)

**Disclosure**: I am the maintainer of `@capacitor-firebase/authentication`.

Comment: please i m newer with ionic capacitor , i get this error when i test the login in a real android mobile, ror logging in with Google: Error: "FirebaseAuthentication" plugin is not implemented on android, how fix it please , i have used the firebase Android SDk .thanks